# Refer to other arguments in Powershell's ValidateScript - in an ordered way

Tags: powershell, validation, parameters, parameter-passing

[image]

So, as seen in the screenshot when the arguments passed in different order, the behavior of validateScript changes. Is there a way to prevent this? (I don't want to change order of the parameters & I'm willing to run the script both ways)

```
Param(
[Parameter(mandatory=$false)]
[string]$XXXArg1,

[Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[validateScript({
    Write-Host "validating XXXArg2 = $_ --> XXXArg1 = $XXXArg1"
    $true
})]
[string]$XXXArg2
)
"Executing XXXArg1:$XXXArg1 , XXXArg2:$XXXArg2"
```

Comment: "I don't want to change order of the parameters & I'm willing to run the script both ways". Validate in the script's body then ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So, it's obvious that I may move the validation logic from "validateScript" to the function's body but I want to use parameter validation logic provided by powershell.

Comment: Can you post your sample code as *text* so it doesn’t have to be re-typed to investigate? I tend to use tio.run on my phone for Powershell questions, and rekeying code is labourious at best…

Comment: Its a computer bro, how would it know about a variable that is not yet initialized? Order is important in this case